# Passing specific arguments to Boost Python function with default arguments

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to create a nice interface for making HTTP calls in my game engine via Python, I have run into a bit of a problem, however.

I have a single function, `get_async` which launches a [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) request for the specified URL. The function is defined inside an `http_manager` class, like so:

```
struct http_manager
{
    typedef function<void(boost::shared_ptr<http_response>)> response_callback_type;
    typedef function<void(size_t)> write_callback_type;

    void get_async(
        const string& url,
        const http_headers_type& headers = http_headers_type(),
        const http_data_type& data = http_data_type(),
        response_callback_type on_response = nullptr,
        write_callback_type on_write = nullptr
        );
};
```

I am able to successfully make this call in Python:

```
http.get_async('http://www.google.ca')
```

However, I want to make a call like this:

```
http.get_async('http://www.google.ca', on_response=f)
```

The key here is that I want to explicitly specify the arguments by name and let all the others be the defaults, just like in regular Python.

Unfortunately, when I do this, I get the following error back from Python:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    HttpManager.get_async(HttpManager, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    get_async(struct naga::http_manager {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > url)
    get_async(struct naga::http_manager {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > url, class std::vector<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > headers)
    get_async(struct naga::http_manager {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > url, class std::vector<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > headers, class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > data)
    get_async(struct naga::http_manager {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > url, class std::vector<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > headers, class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > data, class std::function<void __cdecl(class boost::shared_ptr<struct naga::http_response>)> on_response)
    get_async(struct naga::http_manager {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > url, class std::vector<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > headers, class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > data, class std::function<void __cdecl(class boost::shared_ptr<struct naga::http_response>)> on_response, class std::function<void __cdecl(unsigned int)> on_write)
```

I'm confused as to why it thinks that the argument signature is `HttpManager.get_async(HttpManager, str)` when I'm clearly passing 3 arguments (`self`, `url` and `on_response`).

Here are the relevant bits from my `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` block:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(http_manager_get_async_overloads, http_manager::get_async, 1, 5)

class_<http_manager, noncopyable>("HttpManager", no_init)
    .def("get_async", &http_manager::get_async, http_manager_get_async_overloads(args("url", "headers", "data", "on_response", "on_write")))
    ;
```

Thank you for reading and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh, geez--I totally missed that bottom portion of your question where you stated that you're already using Boost.Python. My bad!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The overall problem is that C++ only uses default arguments for missing trailing arguments, and Boost.Python does not have values to provide for non-trailing missing arguments.

---

#### The Error Message

When Boost.Python internally fails to dispatch a function, the exception message only captures positional arguments.  The exception message attempts to capture the caller's intentions, but display it in a C++ function call format. As C++ only supports positional arguments, there is no obvious format to displaying non-positional arguments.  Consider this simple [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69ead0f4a5512ac8):

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void f() {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  boost::python::def("f", &f);
}
```

Invoking `example.f(a=0)` throws `Boost.Python.ArgumentError` with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    example.f()
did not match C++ signature:
    f(void)
```

Although Boost.Python is fully aware that the caller provided an argument, the exception only captured positional arguments.  In the above example, there were no positional arguments, so the output is `example.f()`.  In the original question, invoking `http.get_async('http://www.google.ca', on_response=f)` results in the exception showing `HttpManager.get_async(HttpManager, str)` as only two positional arguments were provided: the implicit self argument of type `HttpManager` and a `str` object.

#### Dispatch Failure

In C++, default arguments are not part of the function type.  Furthermore, when invoking a function that has default arguments, the default arguments are only used where trailing arguments are missing.  For instance, consider:

```cpp
void f(int a, int b=1, int c=2);
```

The above function has a type of `void(int, int, int)`, and there is no way to call function `f` and only provide an argument for parameter `a` and `c`.  If one wishes to invoke `f` with a non-default value for parameter `c`, then all three arguments must be provided.

However, if a similar function as declared in Python, one could invoke `f` only providing an argument for parameter `a` and `c` as Python supports keyword arguments:

```cpp
def f(a, b=1, c=2):
    pass

f(0, c=42) # Invokes f(0, b=1, c=42)
```

Consider this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9f934442f0308d4) where a C++ function with default arguments has been provided as an overloaded Python function:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void f(int a, int b=1, int c=2) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(f_overloads, f, 1, 3)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;    
  python::def("f", &f, f_overloads(
    python::args("a", "b", "c")));
}
```

Boost.Python has been told that C++ function `f` has a type of `void(int, int, int)`, and can be invoked with a minimum of 1 argument and a maximum of 3.  Boost.Python is also not aware what the default arguments values are.  Thus, Boost.Python creates overloads to support calling:

- `f(int a)`
- `f(int a, int b)`
- `f(int, a, int b, int c)`

Hence, when one attempts to invoke `example.f(0, c=42)` in Python, the function dispatch will fail, as Boost.Python would need to provide a value for `b` when providing a value for `c`, and a value for `b` has not been specified.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    example.f(int)
did not match C++ signature:
    f(int a)
    f(int a, int b)
    f(int a, int b, int c)
```

This behavior is why `http.get_async('http://www.google.ca', on_response=f)` fails, as there is no way for Boost.Python to invoke:

```cpp
http_manager.get_async(url, ???, ???, on_response);
```

### Provide Default Arguments to Python

To continue with the example, if Python was provided default arguments, it could then provide values for non-trailing arguments.  When exposing a function, one can provide default values for arguments via assigning to the [`boost::python::arg`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation.html#function_invocation_and_creation.boost_python_args_hpp.class_arg_operator) object.  The following [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d2a914f289a078d) exposes function `f` with default arguments:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void f(int a, int b=1, int c=2) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(f_overloads, f, 1, 3)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;    
  python::def("f", &f, f_overloads(
    (python::arg("a"), 
     python::arg("b")=1,
     python::arg("c")=2)));
}
```

With Boost.Python aware of default arguments, it can successfully invoke `example.f(0, c=42)`.

Comment: Given the function signatures, argument types, and names, I recommend reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20828366/1053968) answer for details on handling multithreading with Python callbacks within Boost.Python.

Comment: My callback system is going to be fairly simplistic. All `on_response` and `on_write` callbacks will be deferred until the start of every frame and will be called by the main thread, so I don't think I will need to deal with managing the GIL.